# Finding edges in a graph with similar lengths

Tags: algorithm

I have quite a big problem with inventing an algorithm.

I have two groups of nodes. Say, we have 4 nodes in the first group and another 4 nodes in the second one.
The following figure illustrates this:

[image: Two groups of nodes]

I want to connect nodes from the first group with the nodes from the second group. The algorithm should find an ideal solution where **the lengths of all connections must be as similar as possible** and **each node from one group can be connected just to a single node from the second group.**

An ideal solution is demonstrated in the following picture:

[image]

The following picture demonstrates not an ideal solution, as the lengths of those connections differ too much.

[image: Bad connection between the nodes]

The following table shows the lengths between each node. From this table, I want to find the ideal solution. The solution is encircled.

[image: Table of lengths between nodes.]

And how can I find the best solution when I have groups with a hundred of nodes?
If I try every combination, there will be 100! of combinations, and that's a lot.
I am not able to come up with an algorithm with a reasonable complexity.

Comment: So if minimizing connection-lengths is not important, a valid result could also have relatively far connections, provided the largest difference between any two connection-lengths is minimized?

Comment: @גלעדברקן Yes, that's exactly what I want.

Comment: sorry, I don't get the part with the length... so like using Pythagoras and sum all length together must be minimum or what?

Comment: @Thomas No. The lengths must be as similar as possible.
I don't care about sum.

Comment: Ah you mean you subtract the shortest way from the longest way, and the result should be minimal?

Comment: @LadislavOndris Could it also be "more or less minimal"?

Comment: I'm just throwing ideas here because I'm not much of an expert on these fields, but have you tried to work something out using expected value and/or covariance?

Comment: @Da Mike I don't know what you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Thomas@ asked in the comments, the solution of the problem depends on your definition of "as close as possible". Let's define the set of edges in the solution to be `S`. Assuming the definition was chosen to be minimizing `max(S) - min(S)` (which is a reasonable assumption in practice), then this problem can definitely be solved in polynomial time.

Here's an example of the solution. For 100 nodes it will only take seconds.

### 1

First of all, you must know the [maximum matching problem](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eckingsf/bioinfo-lectures/matching.pdf) for bipartite graphs, and that it can be solved in polynomial time. The most straight-forward [Hungarian Algorithm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HungarianMaximumMatchingAlgorithm.html) takes `O(nm)` in which `n` is the number of nodes and `m` is the number of edges. And for planar graph which is your case, [there are more sophisticated algorithms that can further improve the performance](http://web.eecs.umich.edu/%7Epettie/matching/Mucha-Sankowski-planar-matching-journal-version.pdf).

Let's define this to be a function `Max_Match(X)`, which returns the maximum number of matches in edge set `X`.

This `Max_Match` can be calculated in less than `O(n^1.5)`, in which `n` is the number of nodes. For `n=100`, we have only `n^1.5 = 1000`.

---

### 2

Then let's convert your problem to the maximum matching problem.

Let's define the set of edges `E` to all the edges we can pick from. In your case there are `n*n` edges in `E`, where `n` is the number of nodes on one side.

Let's define function
`F(E, low, high) = {e | e in E and |e| >= low and |e| <= high }`
which means the subset edges of `E` whose lengths are between `[low, high]`

Then for a given pair of numbers `low` and `high`, your problem has a solution if and only if

**`Max_Match( F (E, low, high)) == n`**

---

### 3

However, how do we figure out the value of `low` and `high` ?

The possible values of `low` and `high` are every possible numbers in `{|e|, e in E}`, which has `n^2` numbers. So trying all the possible combinations of `low` and `high` will cost `n^4`. That's a lot.

If we already know `low`, can we figure out `high` without enumeration? The answer is positive. Notice that :

#### lemma 1

If for a number `h` we have
**`Max_Match( F (E, low, h)) == n`**

Then for every number `h' >= h` we also have

**`Max_Match( F (E, low, h')) == n`**

What this means is that we can use binary search to figure out `high` once we fix `low`.

---

### 4

So the framework of the final solution:

```
arr[] = {|e|, e in E}.sort()
for i in range(0, len(arr[])):
  low = i
  h_left = i, h_right = len(arr[])-1
  while h_left <= h_right:
    mid = (h_left+h_right)/2
    if Max_Match( F( E, arr[low], arr[mid]))==n:
      h_right = mid - 1
    else:
      h_left = mid + 1
  if h_left >= low:
    if arr[h_left] - arr[low] <= ans:
      ans = arr[h_left] - arr[low]
```

And `ans` will be the minimal difference between the edges in the solution. This algorithm costs `O(n^3.5 * log(n))`, in which `n` is the number of nodes.

Edit: a simple and ugly implementation of above algorithm in c++ can be found at:
[ideone.com/33n2Tg](http://ideone.com/33n2Tg) . Because I'm short of time, I handcrafted a simple Hungarian algorithm in this solution, which is slow when `n` is large. To achieve better performance you will need the algorithm I included in part 1 for planar graphs.

Comment: What does the Max_Match do?

Comment: Find the maximum matching of a set of edges, as described in part 1 O_O . This answer is divided into 4 parts numbered from 1 to 4 and I recommend it being read in this order.

Comment: But this algorithm doesn't return a set of edges.

Comment: If you are confused by what maximum matching problem is, here's a wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory) . Also any matching algorithm can return the set of edges in the solution. So in the end you can simply call Max_Match( F( E, arr[low], arr[high])) to get the set of edges in the final solution once you find the best value of low and high.

Comment: And if you wonder about the implementation of Max_Match(), the Hungarian is the easiest (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm). Also there's Hopcroft–Karp (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopcroft%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm , which even includes a piece of pseudo code).  For your problem since it's planar graph, you may want to read the paper I included in 1 to have the optimal performance.

Comment: The Hungarian algorithm can't be used in my case. It does something else than I want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115662/discussion-between-lavin-and-ladislav-ondris).

Comment: great idea - i like these kinds of conceptual shifts

Comment: I was thinking about a similar solution. 1. Compute a list of n*n edges between the points and sort them by length. 2. Define a sliding window over that list of edges. 3. With binary search on the window size and by sliding the window through the list find such `w1<w2` that window of size `w2` found a maximum matching of size `n` but the window of size `w1` didn't. -- If there exists an algorithm for [size of] maximum matching that can be updated in time `O(f(n))` whenever an edge is added or removed then this problem can be solved in `O(n^2 f(n) log n) `. Sadly I'm not aware of such an algo

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can easily calculate that with A*. Also a brute force would be O(n!). I think we should use heuristics like genetic algorithm.

You can implement the gen with an array (point A index is connected to the value point B)

[image]

Then you have to generate an gene pool with random genes. The number of genes is not fix... so you have to test a little bit around.

you will need a calculation method:

```
float GetLength(int indexA, int indexB)
{
    return sqrt((pointA[indexA].x - pointB[indexB].x) * (pointA[indexA].x - pointB[indexB].x) + (pointA[indexA].y - pointB[indexB].y) * (pointA[indexA].y - pointB[indexB].y));
}
```

then you also need a fitness function:

```
float Fitness(int gene, int count)
{
    float min = GetLength(0,gene[0]);
    float max = GetLength(0,gene[0]);
    for(int i = 0; i< count;i++)
    {
        min = std::min(min, GetLength(i,gene[i]));
        max = std::max(max, GetLength(i,gene[i]));
    }
    return max-min;
}
```

Also you need to pair them:

```
int* Crossbreed(int* gene1, int* gene2, int count)
{
    int* geneNew = new int[count];
    for(int i = 0; i< count; i++)
    {
        geneNew[gene1[i]] = gene2[i];
    }
    return geneNew;
}
```

The Crossbreed gives us back some kids ;) which has to pass the fitness test. Also you should implement a mutate method, which gives us a mutated gene. This is important to leave local maximal.

At the end you only have to run this in a loop for some time and you will get a extremely good result.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't answer sooner, but at the time, I had no idea what a genetic algorithm is. I'm revisiting old questions and this is truly an interesting solution and I'll definitely try to implement it when I have some time. Thanks!

Comment: Alternatively this could be approximated with simulated annealing, which may be slightly simpler. Also a small improvement, the fitness function can be updated in `O(log n)` time on edge change if you keep a set of edges ordered by length.

Answer (score -1):

Assume that this table has n rows and m columns.
This problem is equivalent to choose n numbers, which is in different rows and different columns, from this table so that the sum of these numbers is minimum.
We can use dfs to find all the combination in n! .but for this problem we can have a [A* search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm).

As for this problem, the heuristic function h(x) is 
[image]

The complexity of this A* algorithm is difficult to calculate, but it frequently perform well.